# Fix faulty connections in Go

Tags: go, server, client

I have a client that is sending (receiving) data to (from) a server. The code of the client is similar to:

```
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:3456")
reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)

for true {
   writer.write(data)
   reader.read()
}
```

Now, assume that the server crashes often leading to `conn` to be faulty. This would imply that the `write` and `read` methods in the `for` loop will not do anything and just return an `error`. Even if the server comes up again in the next few seconds the client's `for` loop code will not be able to communicate with the server since `conn` is faulty.

What I'm trying to achieve is: **Have the client to continue operating when the server comes back up again.** For this, I though of the following approach:

```
    func fixConnection(conn *net.Conn, reader **[]bufio.Reader, writer **[]bufio.Writer) net.Conn {

        for true {

            oneByte := make([] byte, 1, 1)
            reader := bufio.NewReader(*conn)
            _, err := reader.Read(oneByte)
            if err != nil {
                for true {
                    var tmpConn net.Conn
                    tmpConn, err = net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:3456")
                    if err == nil {
                        *conn = tmpConn
                        *reader = bufio.NewReader(*conn)
                        *writer = bufio.NewWriter(*conn)
                    }
                    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
                }
            } else {
                reader.UnreadByte()
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
                continue
            }

        }
}
```

and then I just add one line in the client:

```
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:3456")
reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)

// new line
go fixConnection(&conn, &reader, &writer)

for true {
   writer.write(data)
   reader.read()
}
```

There is at lest one problem with my approach: `bufio` is not thread-safe so while `fixConnection` is changing the readers (writers) there might be an issue. Is there a way to solve this problem without using `sync.Mutex` before operating on readers/writers.

Also, is there a better way to solve my aforementioned problem. Namely, connecting again to the server when the server comes back up again? Note that the server can accept connections by multiple clients at any point in time.

Comment: TCP connections cannot be sustained if one end crashes. You need an application-layer reconnection capability.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. The server can just accept a new client on the fly.

Comment: So far i know, you cant read and write that easily. You must write and close the connection for acknowledgement, then re-open the connection and read and wait for the other side to close the connection for acknowledgement.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just check for errors, something like this

```
func connect(addr string)(*bufio.Reader, *bufio.Writer, Error){
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", addr)  reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    if err != nill{
        return(nil, nil, err)
    }
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    return(reader, writer, nil)
}
for reader, writer, err := connect(adrr);;{
    if err !=nil {
        reader, writer, err = connect(adrr)
        continue
    }
    _, err = writer.write(data)
    err = reader.read()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type ReconnectingWriter struct {
    Dialer func() (net.Conn, error)

    mu   sync.RWMutex
    conn net.Conn
}

func NewReconnectingWriter(dialer func() (net.Conn, error)) *ReconnectingWriter {
    return &ReconnectingWriter{Dialer: dialer}
}

func (rw *ReconnectingWriter) getConn() (net.Conn, error) {
    rw.mu.RLock()
    conn := rw.conn
    rw.mu.RUnlock()

    if conn != nil {
        return conn, nil
    }

    rw.mu.Lock()
    defer rw.mu.Unlock()

    var err error
    if rw.conn == nil {
        rw.conn, err = rw.Dialer()
    }

    return rw.conn, err
}

func (rw *ReconnectingWriter) closeConn() {
    rw.mu.Lock()
    defer rw.mu.Unlock()

    if rw.conn != nil {
        rw.conn.Close()
        rw.conn = nil
    }
}

func (rw *ReconnectingWriter) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        if i > 0 {
            time.Sleep(time.Second) // replace this with exp backoff + jitter
        }

        // try to get a connection
        conn, err := rw.getConn()
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }

        // try to write the data
        n, err := conn.Write(b)
        if err != nil {
            rw.closeConn()
            continue
        }

        return n, err
    }
}

func main() {
    rw := NewReconnectingWriter(func() (net.Conn, error) {
        return net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:9000")
    })
    rw.Write([]byte("hello world"))
}
```

You shouldn't do this though because you'll end up with partial writes. If this is an http server a better solution is to use a load balancer because it can replay the whole request properly. (haproxy or envoy are options)